# Why are computers much smaller than they are fast?

Tags: special-relativity, electric-circuits, information, computer

In any medium there is a finite propagation speed at which information can spread. Special relativity provides an upper bound to that propagation speed, namely the speed of light in vacuum. Signals of light in media, or electric signals in wires come close/are similar to that theoretical maximum.

There is no fundamental difference between "transporting" and "processing" information, e.g., just sending a "bit" trough a wire is not fundamentally different from doing the same while negating the bit after every millimeter of the wire looking like 0101010101. As a more non-trivial example, consider adding two (very large) numbers whose digits are placed at every millimeter along the wire. To add the digits at one place we need the carry from the previous (lower-digit) additions, so the carry is a signal running through the wire which is processed in a non-trivial way. The theoretical maximum speed for this addition should still be the speed of light.

Now, consider the transistors modern computers are made of. The size of a modern CMOS transistor is about 5nm. I don't know what exactly the propagation delay through one of these transistors is, but I think it's supposed to be in the picosecond range, say 10ps. Please correct the numbers if they are very far off. Now, if we would densely pack transistors along a line to "process" the information on the way instead of merely "transporting" the signal, the effective speed of the processing would be 5e-9m/10e-12s=500m/s, which is much slower than the speed of light, by a factor of ~1e6.

So why is sending a signal through a transistor so much slower than sending a signal through a piece of wire? Are there any information processing technologies (maybe something based on light etc.) which provide a "transistor" element where the speed through is comparable to the speed of light? Of course, the "transistor" element should keep the ~speed-of-light propagation speed when downsized to a size comparable to a CMOS transistor (otherwise one might argue a 5nm CMOS transistor itself has ~speed-of-light when we put it in a 1mm box, i.e., pretend its size is 1mm).

I believe that part of the reason might be that transistors are not optimized for that since this is not the bottleneck in common computer architectures. There, signals do not always go from one transistor to a neighboring one but often are sent through "long" pieces of wire in between. Then the propagation delay on those long pieces of wire due to the speed of light might be of the same order as the propagation delay through the individual transistors, such that optimizing the latter does not yield much benefit. However, if modern computers were cellular automata, improving the propagation delay through a single transistor would provide a huge potential for speedup (up to ~1e6). Are there any areas (maybe graphics cards/parallel computing) where improving propagation delay of single transistors plays an important practical role? Are there any developments in transistor technology targeted at improving the propagation delay rather than the size?

Comment: firstly, 5nm is the gate size not the entire transistor (we can probably partially attribute that misconception to marketing). secondly, as Austin Fox mentioned, it takes time for charge to build up, ie. capacitance at the junctions. thirdly, you won't get propagation at the speed of light, even in modern photonic chips, because the field interacts with surrounding material which slows it down. And because information propagates as a pulse rather than the phase velocity, as a pulse contains other frequencies which travels yet slower again due to material and waveguide dispersion.

Comment: @antimony Thanks, so what is rough size of the entire transistor, say for "the 5nm process". I found it very hard to find specifics on this on the internet. And can you also tell me whether the 10ps I came up with is approximately correct for such a transistor?

Comment: Btw, I'm not saying information should propagate at exactly the speed of light, just that this is a theoretical maximum which one could try to achieve. So I'm saying there should be some kind of information processing technology which at least comes near that theoretical maximum for its gates. By near I mean maybe sth like 10%. However, transistor technology seems to miss this maximum by ~1e-6.

Comment: sorry late response. i'm not that familiar with the 5nm process. regarding your second question, what you're looking for are photonic integrated circuits $^{1}$, they are achieving such speeds, the problem is they are currently quite large, eg. up to many 10s of micron per digital logic gate. shrinking the footprint is an active area of research. Other exciting photonic IC approaches to computation are closer to the analog computing realm. $^{1}$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonic_integrated_circuit

Answer (score 3):

For a wire, a vast number of electrons are present. They barely move. Each electron only needs to move slightly to play its part in guiding the electromagnetic field along the wire. The signal propagates at the speed of light in the insulation.

Consider an N channel MOSFET. It blocks the propagation of the signal when switched off because there are no electrons in the channel. To turn it on so that it behaves like a wire, the gate attracts electrons into the channel. That process moves at the speed of the electrons, which are [much slower than light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_velocity). Then, to turn it back off, the electrons must be extracted from the channel, again at the speed the electrons move.

These "transit time" effects are what control the speed of electronic devices.

Comment: I don't think the transit times are the limiting factor for prop. delay but rather the RC times of the output-input drive..Do you have some sources or order of magnitude estimates?

Answer (score 2):

Someone else with more knowledge can correct me, but I think it might have to due with either the capacitive effect or the field effect in circuits. 1) electrical components often have some capacitive characteristics which are time dependent, therefore for transistors and other components to fully cycle on or off, there is time which must pass for charges to move around. 2) the field development across FETs is a potential difference, it takes time for the charges in the FET to react to the changing field. Maybe these two are saying the same thing?
Another factor is that processors base operations on physical clock signals from a crystal or MEMS device. The accuracy of these is likely related to their frequency so that a cycle of processing hits a limit where it has to wait for the next clock cycle to avoid some problems. Lots of weird things happen when shuffling charges around at that scale and speed.

You might be interested in a video by "Huygens Optics" where he attempts to construct optical logic gates like you described.

Comment: Plus one would be surprised at just how long the wires are on a modern chip, one of the reasons on-chip optical interconnects are a thing.

Answer (score 1):

In CMOS every input to a transistor or gate is driven by a precious CMOS output.

So in all cases you end up with a rather high source impedance R (say 10 kOhm) driving a capacitive input C (say 1 fF).

The charging/discharging process takes time roughly equal to RC (10 ps). And before this time has passed the output of the transistor/gate being charged does not yet change appreciably. Only after RC does the output transition and the next stage will begin being charged/discharged for a duration of RC.

All these charging processes introduce a lot of delay in which signals cannot propagate further.

Comment: Thanks! Did you freely make up the numbers 10kOhm and 1fF, or do you actually know that those are the correct orders of magnitudes for sate-of-the art MOSFET transistors?

Comment: @AndiBauer I don't know exactly but I am positive that these numbers are not *many* orders of magnitude off; I chose them to arrive at your 10 ps value :) Running some numbers, I guess that typical input capacitances today are probably in the ballpark of 10..100s aF and the output impedances are accordingly larger than 10 kOhm. The important bit is, that for a given material/tech, when scaling down, the output impedance rises at least as fast as the capacitance drops, creating a natural "limit" for the prop. delay. That's why there are always new materials or FET architectures.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the clock rate and the propagation delay. It is indeed possible for a change to propagate through a transistor very quickly- the limitations on clock rate are set by other effects.

Some examples:

- All the different logic gates need to stay synchronized. If the clock rate is too fast, it is more likely that imperfections in the clock will cause glitches.
- Even just sending bits across a wire becomes hard at gigahertz frequencies. This is because every little bit of wire becomes an antenna.
- Power consumption increases enormously with clock rate, and quickly passes their thermal dissipation capabilities. Modern processors can be overclocked well above their normal operating frequencies if special care is taken in cooling them. Some people have even cooled cpus with liquid helium in order to break records. This, of course, is extremely impractical and very wasteful.